# Upload functionality (BrowserStack using node.js)

Tags: node.js, browserstack

I have a test for uploading a file (code below) in my application and testing it locally works perfectly. However, when I test it using BrowserStack, BrowserStack cannot access the file in my local machine.

I have checked their documentation about using BrowserStack with Node.js but I haven't seen any documentation about upload functionality. My question is, how do I tell BrowserStack to access my local file?

Has anyone encountered the same issue before?

```
this.selectJmxFile = function(jmxFilePath, done){
   this.driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys(jmxFilePath);

   this.driver.wait(function () {
     return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.css('.test.files.msg.right'));
   }, this.timeout).then(function () {
     driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('.test.files.msg.right')).getText().then(function(text) {
       expect(text).to.equal('1 new file(s) selected');
       done();
     });
   }); 
};
```

where jmxFilePath is set as:

```
this.jmxFile = process.cwd() + '/test/functional/features/data/test.jmx';
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you resolved it?

Comment: No apparently this isn't supported yet by BrowserStack for Node.js

Answer (score 2):

Ok as it turns out this isn't supported yet as this has only been added in selenium v2.45.0 in Node.js. BrowserStack will have this functionality once they support the latest version of selenium. Guess I have to find another workaround!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the file detector and it would be transported to remote Browser Stack machine on which test is running -

```
 webDriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());
```